# Retrying a failed kafka message using Micronaut listener

Tags: apache-kafka, micronaut-kafka

I have used kafka integrations with spring applications in the past and there is a retry mechanism already implemented.
But our team decided to spin up a micronaut service since we found some nice benefits.

I added the micronaut-kafka dependency and set up a listener. The problem is, if a message causes my listener to throw, the exception is logged but the offset is committed.

Is there a way to configure like a number of retries for each message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in micronaut documentation:

- https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-kafka/latest/guide/#kafkaErrors

You can configure an `errorStrategy` on the @KafkaListener annotation

```kotlin
@KafkaListener(
   value = "myGroup", 
   errorStrategy = @ErrorStrategy(value = RETRY_ON_ERROR, retryDelay = "50ms", retryCount=3)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, back in my implementation I created a custom handler with a retry mechanism. Now I see that they added a retry count and delay.